# delete content of particular Excel cells python

Tags: python, excel

I have the following Excel sheet with the following cells:

```
    'A'   'B'   'C' 
1    S     2     T
2    E     F     D
3    K     L     M
4    N     D     F
5    P     E     M
```

I would like to delete the first j lines from column 'B', where j is a list length.

```
list=['2','F','L']
```

Any idea how this can be accomplished?

I would prefer to use openpyxl for this action.

Best regards,

Dan

Comment: Show your effort.

Comment: @MegaIng I was close enough from the first time, but I have tried a stupid method, so I posted the question here. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Found out the solution. Maybe someone else would need it:

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('/media/sf_vboxshared/x.xlsx')
sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
list=['2','F','L']
j=len(list)
for j in range(1,j+1):
        sheet.cell(row=j, column=2).value=None
```

And to check the output can be used:

```
for rowOfCellObjects in sheet['A1':'D6']:
        for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
                print(cellObj.coordinate, cellObj.value)
```

Best regards,
Dan